Using LogMetric in an Azure Function 8.0 isolated mode
I have installed Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, but I get following compiler error:

'ILogger' does not contain a definition for 'LogMetric' and no accessible extension method 'LogMetric'.

Any pointers on what to install to be able to log to metrics from an Azure Function App 8.0?
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.22.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.3.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Storage.Queues" Version="5.4.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Timer" Version="4.3.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.17.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs" Version="3.0.39" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="5.3.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" Version="5.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="8.0.0" />


Can you provide your configuration

It works for me and the pacakages i have are :
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.2.0" />```

Thanks. I added it to main post. What usings do you have?

The issue seems to be with your packages and after  changing the packages to below,  it worked for me:
I have  used Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights package.
My packages in csproj:
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.17.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="8.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  

Function1.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp182
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;
        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }
        [Function("Function1")]
        public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Hello Rithwik, Func Started");
            _logger.LogMetric("rithwik", 8);
            return new OkObjectResult("Hello Rithwik, Func Ended");
        }
    }
}

Program.cs:
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();

Output:
In Application Insights:

In local:


Worked for me. Thanks al ot appreciated.
